# check textfield has value before redirecting to another view - swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've been learning swift for the past 3 hours, so far so good I'm currently passing hard coded data from one view to another.  The issue I'm trying to resolve is the following.

I have one text field on my view, if the user has entered data into that field then I allow them to navigate to the next page after the button has been pressed, if the textfield is empty then I display an error message, seems simple right? Well I can't figure this one out unfortunately, On the button I created a push segue method so once clicked it will go from view one to view two, now I have conditioned this function to check if the textfield is empty if so don't redirect however when I click the button I see the error message but it still redirects? this is my current code:

```
 @IBOutlet var txtfield1: UITextField!
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if txtfield1.text.isEmpty
    {
        nameLabel.text = "error don't redirect"
    }
    else{

        let newVC: SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController

        let passedPhrase = "redirect to new controller / view"

        newVC.receivedPhrase = passedPhrase

    }
}
```

Can anyone shed any light into why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is right, but you need to override this function `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier`.

You need to use this to prevent `performSegueWithIdentifier` if your text is empty

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?,sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    if txtfield1.text.isEmpty {
        return false
    } 
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, so this function you have provided me does that replace my current function specified in my original question?

Comment: Your code above is right, but you must add this to check whether you should `performSegue` or not. It will work.

Comment: You also missed the '?' after String in the parameters.

Comment: Ok, I've just added `?` :).

Answer (score 0):

`prepareForSegue` notifies the view controller that a segue is about to be performed.

Use `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier`to determines whether the segue with the specified identifier should be performed.

So you should check if text is empty in `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier`

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String,sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    if txtfield1.text.isEmpty {
        return false
        print("empty")
    } else{
        return true
    }
}
```